# How to have star rating output "__ out of 5"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made this function in React that allows users to click one of 5 stars and it visually shows how many stars were "selected" (a 5-star rating system).
This function is in its own .js file in a React app, and it returns a div element that is rendered in a different .js file.

My problem is that I want to display how many stars the user clicked (ex. 3 out of 5 stars), but I don't know how to get that information from the .js file with the function to the other .js file where the div element is rendered.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const StarRating = () => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(0);
    return (
      <div className="star-rating">
        {[...Array(5)].map((star, index) => {
          index += 1;
          return (
            <button class="star"
              type="button"
              key={index}
              className={index <= (hover || rating) ? "on" : "off"}
              onClick={() => setRating(index)}
              onMouseEnter={() => setHover(index)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHover(rating)}
            >
              <span className="star">&#9863;</span>
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default StarRating;
```

Comment: Please explain your code.

Comment: className={index <= hover || index <= rating ? "on" : "off"}

Comment: You have to correct your className statement.

Comment: You mean you want the rating in this component to be available elsewhere? Sounds like you’re missing a component that has the star and number components as children and the state is moved up a level. Or you can accept a rating change callback, or use a context, or…

Comment: You have `rating` there in your state, which is set on click of a star when you call `setStar`. That's your star rating.

Comment: As the others have mentioned above, your logic needs to be tweaked a bit and your state should be elevated to a common parent and shared with its children components: [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/star-rating-example-djdis7?file=/src/App.tsx)